# Why does my class's destructor get called when I add instances to a vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

It seems that every time I add an object to the vector m_test, the destructor method is called. Am I missing something? How can I prevent this from happening?

```
class TEST
{
public:
    TEST();
    ~TEST();
    int * x;
};

TEST::TEST()
{
}

TEST::~TEST()
{
... it is called every time I push_back something to the vector ...
    delete x;
}

    vector<TEST> m_test;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        m_test.push_back(TEST());
    }
```

Comment: In C++11, you can use `m_test.emplace_back()` to avoid creating the temporary. In any case, always remember the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here is that you're violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Your class has a destructor so you need a copy-constructor and an assignment operator, too.  Alternatively, you could not allow your class to be copied (for example by making `T(T const&)` and `T& operator=(T const&)` private, or by deriving from `boost::noncopyable`), and then resize the vector instead of using `push_back`.

In the first case, you can just `push_back` your class as you usually would.  In the second, the syntax would be something like

```
std::vector<TEST> vec(5);
// vec now has five default-constructed elements of type TEST.
```

Not doing either of these things is a bad idea, as you are very likely to run into double deletion issues at some point -- even if you think you'll never copy or assign a `TEST` where `x != nullptr`, it's much safer to explicitly forbid it.

By the way, if you have member pointers that should be deleted when an object goes out of scope, consider using smart pointers like `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` (and maybe `auto_ptr` if you're unable to use Boost or C++11).

Comment: Thank you Anton, I am new to C++ programming, and never heard of Rule of Three. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Where did you learn this...? My previous CPP course totally sucks...

Answer (score 9):

It's not called *when you `push_back`*, it's called *when the temporary is destroyed*.

To fix it in your example:

```
TEST test;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    m_test.push_back(test);
}
```

Should only call it once.

Your code is creating a temporary `TEST` within the loop, using it in `push_back`, then that temporary is going out of scope when the loop ends/repeats and getting destroyed. That occurs exactly as it should, since the temporary `TEST` needs cleaned up.

If you want to avoid that, you need to do anything else but make a temporary object for each push. One potential solution is to:

```
vector<TEST> m_test(5); // Note reserving space in the vector for 5 objects

std::fill(m_test.begin(), m_test.end(), TEST()); // Fill the vector with the default ctor
```

Depending on how your STL is optimized, this may not need to make multiple copies.

You may also be able to get better handling if you implement a copy constructor in your `TEST` class, like:

```
TEST::TEST(const TEST & other)
{
    x = new int(*other.x); // Not entirely safe, but the simplest copy ctor for this example.
}
```

Whether this is appropriate, or how you handle it, depends on your class and its needs, but you should typically have a copy constructor when you have defined your own regular constructor and destructor (otherwise the compiler will generate one, and in this case, it will result in copied and hanging pointers to `x`).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid destruction of a temporary *and* to avoid copy constructors, consider using [vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) or [vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back). Here's an example using `emplace_back`:

```
vector<TEST> m_test;
m_test.reserve(5); 
for ( uint i=0; i<5; i++ ) 
{
    m_test.emplace_back();
}
```

The vector element will be constructed in-place without the need to copy. When vt is destroyed, each vector element is automatically destroyed.

c++0x is required (use `-std=c++0x` with gnu). `#include <vector>` is of course also required.

If a default constructor is not used (for example, if the `TEST::x` was a reference instead of a pointer), simply add arguements to the call to `emplace_back()` as follows:

```
class TEST
{
public:
    TEST( int & arg) : x(arg) {;} // no default constructor
    int & x; // reference instead of a pointer.
};

. . . 

int someInt;

vector<TEST> m_test;
m_test.reserve(5);
for ( uint i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
    m_test.emplace_back( someInt ); // TEST constructor args added here.
}
```

The `reserve()` shown is optional but insures that sufficient space is available before beginning to construct vector elements.

Answer (score 1):

`vector.push_back()` copies the given object into its storage area. The temporary object you're constructing in the `push_back()` call is destroyed immediately after being copied, and that's what you're seeing. Some compilers may be able to optimize this copy away, but yours apparently can't.

Answer (score 1):

In `m_test.push_back(TEST());`, TEST() will create an temporary variable. After the vector copy it to its own memory, the temporary variable is destructed.

You may do like this:

```
vector<TEST> m_test(5, TEST());
```

Answer (score 1):

The destructor is not only being called for the temporary variable.

The destructor will also get called when the capacity of the vector changes.

This happens often on very small vectors, less so on large vectors.

This causes:

A new allocation of memory (size based on a growth metric, not just size+1)
Copy of the old elements into the new allocation
Destruction of the elements in the old vector
Freeing of the old vector memory.
Copy construction of the new item onto the end of the new new vector.

See the third answer here:
[Destructor is called when I push_back to the vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798396/destructor-is-called-when-i-push-back-to-the-vector)